# How to always go back to home URL/directory in HTML?

Tags: html, dynamics-365, adxstudio-portals, dynamics-crm-portals

I hope everyone is well.

Currently I'm stuck on HTML pathing, in short I want to always be taken back to "SignIn" page when I log out from Dyanimcs CRM Portals, it does not do this when I am in i.e the following URL https://test.microsoftcrmportals.com/support/edit-case/Account/Login/LogOff?returnUrl=/SignIn however, when I am in URL https://test.microsoftcrmportals.com/support/ and click sign out it does take me to https://test.microsoftcrmportals.com/SignIn

How do I always tell to my code to always root to home then SignIn url, becuase currently my code gets confused when its in multiple paths i.e. like the above?

```
{% assign homeurl = website.adx_partialurl %}

<a href="{% if homeurl%}/{{ homeurl }}{% endif %}Account/Login/LogOff?returnUrl=/SignIn"
```

Would really appreciate some answers, how do I go back to https://test.microsoftcrmportals.com/SignIn, regardless what path im in? i believe is something like ../SignIn or maybe something different dont know?

Comment: The partial URL is https://test.microsoftcrmportals.com/support/edit-case

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to add `~/` before `Account/Login/LogOff?returnUrl=/SignIn` the solution is

```
{% assign homeurl = website.adx_partialurl %}

<a href="{% if homeurl%}/{{ homeurl }}{% endif %}~/Account/Login/LogOff?returnUrl=/SignIn"
```